# appsettings.json being read from $(ProjectDir) not $(OutDir)

Tags: asp.net-core

Running AspNetCore locally in VisualStudio I am seeing `appsettings.json` being served from the source directory rather than from the output directory under `bin`.
This is annying because I have a build step to set a value in it

```
    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
        <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
        <ImplicitUsings>disable</ImplicitUsings>
    <AzureBuild>$(Build)</AzureBuild>

    <BuildName Condition=" '$(AzureBuild)' == '' ">$([System.Environment]::MachineName)_$([System.DateTime]::Now.ToString(yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm))</BuildName>
    <BuildName Condition=" '$(AzureBuild)' != '' ">$(AzureBuild)</BuildName>
</PropertyGroup>

  <UsingTask TaskName="ReplaceFileText" TaskFactory="RoslynCodeTaskFactory" AssemblyFile="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Core.dll">
    <ParameterGroup>
      <InputFilename ParameterType="System.String" Required="true" />
      <OutputFilename ParameterType="System.String" Required="true" />
      <MatchExpression ParameterType="System.String" Required="true" />
      <ReplacementText ParameterType="System.String" Required="true" />
    </ParameterGroup>
    <Task>
      <Using Namespace="System" />
      <Using Namespace="System.IO" />
      <Using Namespace="System.Text.RegularExpressions" />
      <Code Type="Fragment" Language="cs">
        <![CDATA[  
          File.WriteAllText(
            OutputFilename,
            Regex.Replace(File.ReadAllText(InputFilename), MatchExpression, ReplacementText)
            );
        ]]>
      </Code>
    </Task>
  </UsingTask>

  <Target Name="appsettingsSetBuildId" BeforeTargets="AfterBuild">
    <!-- "Build" doesn't work - maybe it's not a target? -->
    <ReplaceFileText InputFilename="$(OutDir)appsettings.json" OutputFilename="$(OutDir)appsettings.json" MatchExpression="{BuildName}" ReplacementText="$(BuildName)" />
    <Message Importance="High" Text="Replaced {BuildName} with $(BuildName) in $(OutDir)appsettings.json." />
  </Target>
```

In my `bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1` directory I see that `appsetting.json` has been updated, but in code I am seeing the value from the `appsettings.json` in the source directory.

What's going on?!

Update: also not working (seeing value from source file) after publishing from VisualStudio to an Azure web app.

Answer (score 0):

In program.cs you could set the base path of IConfigrationBuiler as below,if you don't set,the default value would be solutionpath when you debug ,and you could read settings from other json files with the codes below

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
                Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                    .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) =>
                    {
                        //default basepath is your SolutionPath
                        config.SetBasePath("somepath");
                        config.AddJsonFile("somejson.json",
                        optional: true,
                        reloadOnChange: true);
                    })
                    .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                    {                    
                        webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                    });
```

Also,you could update  appsettings.json from your solution path together with that in bin floder

```
<ReplaceFileText InputFilename="$(InputPath)appsettings.json" OutputFilename="$(InputPath)appsettings.json" MatchExpression="Nihao"  ReplacementText="Hellow" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't work out what's going on with the config file -- quite disappointingly. So I've used a custom assembly attribute instead

```
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Assembly, AllowMultiple = false)]
    public class BuildNameAttribute : Attribute
    {
        public string BuildName { get; set; }

        public BuildNameAttribute(string buildName)
        {
            BuildName = buildName;
        }

        public static string GetBuildName()
        {
            Assembly a = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly();
            BuildNameAttribute bna = a.GetCustomAttribute<BuildNameAttribute>();
            return bna?.BuildName ?? "";
        }
    }
```

and

```
    <AzureBuild>$(Build)</AzureBuild>
    <BuildName Condition=" '$(AzureBuild)' == '' ">$([System.Environment]::MachineName)_$([System.DateTime]::Now.ToString(yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm))</BuildName>
    <BuildName Condition=" '$(AzureBuild)' != '' ">$(AzureBuild)</BuildName>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <AssemblyAttribute Include="Company.BuildNameAttribute">
      <_Parameter1>$(BuildName)</_Parameter1>
    </AssemblyAttribute>
  </ItemGroup>
```